# Email notification 60 days in advance for subscription renewal

Tags: sourceforge-appscript, py-appscript, rb-appscript

I have a google sheet where I have a list of subscriptions, when the subscription will expire, and another column with the notice date (which is 60 days before the expiration date) so I know I have an upcoming renewal.

I want to get email notifications through app script so I don’t have ti continuously open the sheets to check, rather I just get an email notifying me.

I have already created another sheet that just has my name and my email that I was testing to see if I can get an email notification through that which works because I found it on another website but I’m not sure how to do the rest.

Comment: Sorry, I also want the reminder to say. “Reminder: (subscription name) has an upcoming renewal”